# complexity on recursive Big-O

Tags: recursion, complexity-theory

I have a Computer Science Midterm tomorrow and I need help determining the complexity of these recursive functions. I know how to solve simple cases, but I am still trying to learn how to solve these harder cases. Any help would be much appreciated and would greatly help in my studies, Thank you!

```
fonction F(n)
    if n == 0
        return 1
    else
        return F(n-1) * n

fonction UniqueElements(A[0..n-1])
    for i=0 to i <= n-2 do
        for j=i+1 to j <= n-1 do
            if A[i] == A[j]
                return false
        return true

fonction    BinRec(n)
    if n == 1
        return 1
    else
        return BinRec(floor(n/2)) + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

For hands on learning, you can plug the functions into a program, and test their worst case scenario performance.

When trying to calculate O by hand, here are some things to remember

- The +, -, *, and / offsets can be ignored. So 1 to n+5 and 1 to 5n is considered equivalent to 1 to n.
- Also, Only the highest order of magnitude counts, so for O 2^n + n^2 + n, 2^n grows the fastest, so it is equivalent to O 2^n
- With recursive functions, you are looking at how many times the function is called in the method (the split count) and how much it needs to be called (the depth, usually is equal to list length). So the final O will be depth_count^split_count
- With loops, each nested loop multiplies to the one it's in, and sequential loops add, so (1-n){(1-n){}}  (1-n){} is (n * n) + n) => n^2 + n =(only highest growth counts)> n^2
- PRACTICE! You will need to practice to get the hang of the gatchas of growth rate and how control flows interact. (so do online practice [quiz](http://bigoquiz.com/)s)

```js
function F(n){
    count++
    if (n == 0)
        return 1
    else
        return F(n-1) * n
}

function UniqueElements(A){
    for (var i=0 ; i <= A.length-2; i++){
        for (var j=i+1;j <= A.length-1; j++){
            if (A[i] == A[j]){
                return false
            }
        }
   }
                
return true
}

function BinRec(n) {
    count++
    if (n == 1)
        return 1
    else
        return BinRec(Math.floor(n/2)) + 1
}

count = 0;
console.log(F(10));
console.log(count);
count = 0;
console.log(UniqueElements([1,2,3,5]));
console.log(count);
count = 0;
console.log(BinRec(40));
console.log(count);
```